# Using a JQuery countdown timer in WordPress, works perfect in Chrome but in I.E. all the numbers are zeros. Has anyone else ran into this before?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, countdown

Using a JQuery countdown timer in WordPress, works perfect in Chrome but in I.E. all the numbers are zeros.  Has anyone else ran into this before?

```
<script>
jQuery(function(){
    var difTime = parseInt((Date.parse('2015-10-04 8:00:20')/1000) - (new Date().getTime()/1000));
    var newclock = jQuery('#newclock').FlipClock({ clockFace: 'DailyCounter'});
    newclock.setTime(difTime);
    newclock.setCountdown(true);
    var days = newclock.time.getDays();
    if(days > 99 && days < 999){
        jQuery('#newclock .days .flip-clock-label').css('right', '-86px');
    }
    if(days > 999 && days < 9999){
        jQuery('#newclock .days .flip-clock-label').css('right', '-110px');
    }
    if(days > 9999){
        jQuery('#newclock .days .flip-clock-label').css('right', '-132px');
    }
});
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I changed the '2015-10-04 8:00:20' to '2015/10/04 8:00:20' and Eureeka! Fixed